# Logstash output::stdout ignores conditional statement

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am facing a problem as I want to make logstash (version 7.11.1) additionally redirect output to stdout if `DEBUG` environment variable is set to `true`. But it seems, it sends output to `stdout` all the time as long as this plugin is defined anywhere in `output` section:

```
output {
  if [@metadata][service] == "application" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"
      manage_template => false
      index => "app-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }

  if "[${DEBUG}]" == "true" {
    stdout {}
  }
}
```

I have tried other statements that really could never be `true`, but it always prints to stdout.

Am I doing something wrong, or this is standard on logstash?

[UPDATE]

Apparently, there was default `logstash.conf` file in docker image (`logstash:7.11.1`), that contained `output { stdout {} }` by default. Thats why I always got feed to my `stdout`.

Anyways, after overriding `logstash.conf` I faced problems that were easily solved using answers below.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing environment variables in conditionals is not supported. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5115) on github requesting it. It has not been addressed since it was opened five years ago and I do not expect that to change.

The workaround is do reference the environment variable in a filter.

```
filter { mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][debug]" => "${DEBUG}" } } }
```

and then reference that in the conditional

```
if [@metadata][debug] == "true" { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables in conditionals don't seem to be supported yet (https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5115). The workaround is to assign your DEBUG env var to a metadata field, and then use that metadata field in the conditional. e.g.,

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][debug]" => "${DEBUG}" }
  }
}

output {
  ...
  if [@metadata][debug] == "true" {
    stdout {}
  }
}
```